# ¿Función ajax no funciona en laravel 5.6 usando los archivos js que vienen por defecto?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Hola a todos estoy desarrollando una aplicación web, un `CRUD` y utilizo Ajax el cual me funciona usando algunos cdn pero yo quiero utilizar los archivos que vienen por defecto en `laravel` en la carpeta `public`, pero al utilizarlos deja de funcionar mis funciones Ajax, les dejo mi código.

cdn que funcionan:

```
 <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

llamada a ajax:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
            $('.modal-orden_de_compra').text('Delete');
            $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#orden_de_compra_delete').val($(this).data('orden_de_compra'));
            $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
            id = $('#id_delete').val();
            orden_de_compra = $('#orden_de_compra_delete').val();
            alert(id);
        });
        $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: 'posts/' + id,
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    toastr.success('Pedido eliminado exitosamente!', 'Notificación', {timeOut: 5000});
                    $('.item' + data['pedido_id']).remove();
                    alert('.item' + data['pedido_id']);
                }
            });
        });
```

funciona perfecto pero al cambiar los cdn  por el siguiente código deja de funcionar las funciones ajax

```
 <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>


    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: para que funcione ajax.. debes tener jquery dado que ajax es parte de jquery... desconosco que sea js/app.js .... al parecer no es jquery..es por eso que no te va a funcionar ajax

Comment: la libreria mas importante es jquery.min.js .. que seria jquery .. no importa si no usas css.. o bootstrap..lo que importa es que incluyas tu jquery.. yo te sugiero que descargues el js de jquery y lo pongas en la carpeta que desees.. como public

Comment: @Tegito123 ajax no pertenece a jquery

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Tegito123 ajax es una api del navegador, jquery solo hace fácil usarlo investiga bien

Comment: Puedes usar ajax con jquery, con axios, la api nativa fetch, con la api xmlhttprequest

Comment: Tampoco me funciona usando los cdn de Bootstrap 4, al parecer solo funciona con el 3, me carga el jquery pero al usar bootstrap 4 la funcion delete ajax deja de funcionar

Comment: y si cargo el jquery utilizo la funcion alert, pero repito al cambiar los cdn que contienen el bootstrap.min.js de la version  bootstrap 3 a la 4 deja de funcionar, tambien lo intente con el codigo de laravel que muestro arriba el cual carga el javascript y el jquery, la consola tampoco muestra errores

Answer (score 0):

Les dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo es importante escribir la clase `class="modal-content"` y yo cometí el error de escribir `class="modal-cliente"`, no sabia que era importante para que funcionara el codigo.